# Is it possible to generate a log file of the use of a windows user?

Tags: windows-7

Assume user A powers on a windows machine at 9:00 am; launch MS outlook at 9:05 am, checks and replies some emails for about 20 mins; launch Chrome at 9:25 am searches something for about 10 mins; and power off the machine.

Is it possible to generate a log like that on windows 7 or windows 10?

It seems "windows event viewer" only contains power on, power off, some errors, how about the normal use like MS outlook and Chrome?

Comment: You can turn Auditing ON for Windows 10, 8 and 7 workstations to see what files are used. I do not think you can get more granular than that..   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/audit-policy-recommendations

Comment: @John Thank you. To stats how long Chrome runs, which file I should audit?

Comment: You would need to go into Event Viewer (Audit results go in Event Viewer) and set up a custom view for Chrome.